# Converting a string into a dictionary

Tags: string, dictionary, python-3.x

I want to convert a string such as:

```
"this is a sentence"
```

and turn it into a dictionary such as:

```
{1:"this", 2:"is", 3:"a", 4:"sentence"}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> dict(enumerate("this is a sentence".split(),start=1))
{1: 'this', 2: 'is', 3: 'a', 4: 'sentence'}
```

Explination:

`dict()` accepts a iterable which contains tuples of the form `(key,value)`. These are turned into key value pairs. `split()` will separate the sentence by whitespace. `enumerate` goes over all the values generated by `.split` and returns `(index,value)`. These tuples are consumed by `dict()` producing the desired dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate` makes this simple:

```
dict(enumerate(sentence.split(), start=1))
```

- `sentence.split()` splits up the sentence on whitespace into a list of words.
- `enumerate()` makes an iterable of key-value pairs: `[(1, 'this'), (2, 'is'), ...]`
- `dict()` accepts an iterable of key-value pairs and turns it into a dictionary.

Although if your keys are integers, why don't you just use a list?